# Differences in SciKit Learn, Keras, or Pytorch

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, scikit-learn, pytorch

Are these libraries fairly interchangeable?

Looking here, https://stackshare.io/stackups/keras-vs-pytorch-vs-scikit-learn, it seems the major difference is the underlying framework (at least for PyTorch).

Comment: Keras and Pytorch, more or less yeah. scikit-learn is much broader and does tons of data science related tasks including imputation, feature encoding, and train/test split, as well as non-NN-based models. You’d be hard pressed to use a NN in python without using scikit-learn at some point

Comment: Other than the things mentioned by @BallpointBen scikit-learn is much more focused on training traditional ML models (Pretty much everything that isn't deep learning). In deep learning PyTorch is computation library that is pretty low level. Keras is a higher level deep learning library (with a similarish API to scikit-learn) that runs on top usually tensorflow (but support other backends).

Answer (score 146, accepted):

Yes, there is a major difference.

SciKit Learn is a general machine learning library, built on top of NumPy. It features a lot of machine learning algorithms such as support vector machines, random forests, as well as a lot of utilities for general pre- and postprocessing of data. It is not a neural network framework.

PyTorch is a deep learning framework, consisting of

1. A vectorized math library similar to NumPy, but with GPU support and a lot of neural network related operations (such as softmax or various kinds of activations)
2. Autograd - an algorithm which can automatically calculate gradients of your functions, defined in terms of the basic operations
3. Gradient-based optimization routines for large scale optimization, dedicated to neural network optimization
4. Neural-network related utility functions

Keras is a higher-level deep learning framework, which abstracts many details away, making code simpler and more concise than in PyTorch or TensorFlow, at the cost of limited hackability. It abstracts away the computation backend, which can be TensorFlow, Theano or CNTK. It does not support a PyTorch backend, but that's not something unfathomable - you can consider it a simplified and streamlined subset of the above.

In short, if you are going with "classic", non-neural algorithms, neither PyTorch nor Keras will be useful for you. If you're doing deep learning, scikit-learn may still be useful for its utility part; aside from it you will need the actual deep learning framework, where you can choose between Keras and PyTorch but you're unlikely to use both at the same time. This is very subjective, but in my view, if you're working on a novel algorithm, you're more likely to go with PyTorch (or TensorFlow or some other lower-level framework) for flexibility. If you're adapting a known and tested algorithm to a new problem setting, you may want to go with Keras for its greater simplicity and lower entry level.

Comment: Thanks @Jatentaki! This is thorough and definitely helpful in understanding the differences and when to use them.

Comment: You can build neural net classifiers in Sci-Kit though, [right](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neural_networks_supervised.html)?

Comment: @JamesL. yes, you can but it's more of a toy feature for learning without hardware (GPU) acceleration

Comment: This is the ideal answer to this question. I have searched far and wide and this is the best explanation I have seen!

Comment: Just wanted to also say: this was an excellent answer. I'm starting to get into the field and there is so much to learn. you really clarified the difference between two of the libraries that I've seen mentioned the most. Thanks.